# Converting a string to a Dictionary of Dictionary<string, List<string>> in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have the follow string:

```
string mystring = "{yhxj7027DO=[3], lzpd7453EH=[2, 3]}"
```

I would like to convert it to a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where a key for example can be `yhxj7027DO`; and a value `[3]`

I tried  `Dictionary<string, List<string>> test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>(mystring);`
but it does not work. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: In what way "it does not work"? Surely you'd have an error message.

Comment: I have this error "non-invocable member Dictionary<TKey, TValue> cannot be used like a method"

Comment: `{yhxj7027DO=[3], lzpd7453EH=[2, 3]}` is malformed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error *`Error: Parse error on line 1: Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'`*.  Is that a typo in your question, and if so, can you share some actual JSON?  (Well formed JSON would look like e.g. `{"yhxj7027DO":[3], "lzpd7453EH":[2, 3]}`) Or are you really trying to parse non-JSON with Json.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string has nothing to do with json, but you can convert it to json

```
     string mystring = "{yhxj7027DO=[3], lzpd7453EH=[2, 3]}";

     var jObj = new JObject();

    var strArr = mystring.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split("],");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
    {
        strArr[i] = strArr[i].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        var arr = strArr[i].Split("=", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
        jObj.Add(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }

    foreach (var prop in jObj.Properties())
    prop.Value = new JArray(((string)prop.Value).Split(",",StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries));


Dictionary<string, List<int>> resultInt = jObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
```

result

```
{"yhxj7027DO":[3],"lzpd7453EH":[2, 3]}
```

you can use the same code to convert to List < string > as well

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = jObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```

result

```
{"yhxj7027DO":["3"],"lzpd7453EH":["2","3"]}
```

Comment: Thanks @serge. But your example does not work for with List of string (Dictionary<string, string[]>). I have this error when I try to use your example: Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: :. Path 'key2[0]', line 1, position 36.

Comment: @user3841581 You are welcome! I never post the code that was not tested. As you can see I am using Dictionary<string, int[]>, I can't see why I have to use string array it it is an int array

Comment: @user3841581 But I updated my answer, now it can deserialize both

Comment: it works very well now. Thank you